# Is it possible to install your iOS app to all device simulators with XCode at once

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I want to learn a quick way to install my iOS app to all types of simulator (iphone4s, iphon5s, ipad2 ..) at once in XCode GUI.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this possible now that Xcode 9 allows multiple simulators to be open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible but non-trivial.

Installation of an app can be done using simctl, the CLI to CoreSimulator.framework.  You can run 'xcrun simctl install  ' to install an app to a particular device.

For this to work, the device needs to be booted, but the Non-UI experience you get through 'xcrun simctl boot' is currently not sufficient for this to work.  You need the device to be fully booted (as Simulator.app does) for the install to work.

Simulator.app unfortunately only allows one device to be booted at a time, but there's nothing stopping you from creating multiple copies of Simulator.app (one for each device you want running).  You'll want to edit Info.plist to change the bundle identifier so they don't conflict with eachother and resign the app bundle with the codesign utility.

Answer (score 0):

No, the iOS Simulator cannot run multiple apps or multiple devices simultaneously.

Comment: I meant installing my app to all devices at once, not running multiple instances.

Comment: Look at the command line tools, maybe you can write a script or a build phase that does it, but there is nothing by default that will do that.